# How to remove the window border for gnome-terminal?

Tags: compiz, gnome-terminal

Is it possible to remove the window border for gnome-terminal only in Compiz? I recall that it used to be possible to do this with a command-line option, but I can not find it anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out this can be easily done using the Compiz window decoration plugin. In the 'Decoration windows' field enter:

```
!(class=Gnome-terminal)
```

To further customize this you can hide a specific set of terminals by entering in the 'Decoration windows' field:

```
!(title=tmux_terminal)
```

Then, borders will only be disabled for terminals that are started as follows:

```
gnome-terminal --title=tmux_terminal
```